# How To get Payment By Paid Apps uploaded and about service taxes in Google Play Store?

Tags: android, google-cloud-platform, google-play, google-play-services, google-play-console

I am an android programmer . Recently I have developed an android software and now want to uploaded this apps in Google Play Store . I want to up this app as paid apps . I have come to know that I have to open an account in Google Play Store by $30 .

But I have some confusion regarding this whole matter . Can u plz help me by answering the following question .

1. WHEN people buy the app from google play store how will I get paid for the app.
2. Who will pay service tax (It varies from country to country if the app is released in multiple countries.) for the app? Google or Person who releases the app. If google is paying the taxes, Then I think only amount after deduction of taxes and google service charges will be deposited in our account, RIGHT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The system varies based on countries:

- In most countries you set the price in the Play Console which includes the tax. E.g. You set a price of $2 inc. tax 20%. User pays $2. This means the price with no tax is $1.67. Now Google takes its 30% and you're left with $1.17
- In some other countries, E.g United States, you set the price with no tax and then the tax is added on automatically as it varies by state. E.g. You set a price with no tax of $2. Tax is 20% so user pays $2.40. Google takes its 30% and you get $1.40.

*Please note: Values used for demonstration purposes*

After these calculations are made, the money gets added on to your Google Play Console Account. On the 15th day of the month, if your earnings are over the payment threshold, the money will be transferred to your bank account. This usually takes a few days.

Comment: america adds VAT also depending on state regulations so it can vary nationally- don't take fixed price advice

Comment: Hi, do you know maybe how/where issue an tax invoice for that against Google?

Answer (score 0):

The payments will be transferred to your account once in a month. For example Payments of March will be initiated after April 15th and it takes a few more days for you to receive payments. Further more taxes (30% Google Service Charges + Country wise Service Tax) will be deducted on your payments.

Comment: Hi, do you know maybe how/where issue an tax invoice for that against Google?